# How to select from JSON in database and show as text

Tags: json, vb.net, oracle, procedure

i have connection between oracle and visual.vb
and in it i exec sone procedure on coracvle
and it retrun json for me
i want to show that jsons parameters as text in .net

```vb
Dim conn As New OracleConnection(constr.ConnectionString)
Dim cmdd As New OracleCommand
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.ConnectionString = constr.ConnectionString
cmdd.Connection = conn
Try
    cmdd.CommandText = "procedure_here"
    cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmdd.Parameters.Add("I_CODE", OracleType.Number).Value = ViewState("Code")
    cmdd.Parameters.Add("old_id", OracleType.Number).Value = old_id
    cmdd.Parameters.Add("new_id", OracleType.Number).Value = new_id
    Dim Paramout As New OracleClient.OracleParameter


    Paramout.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Paramout.DbType = DbType.Int16
    Paramout.ParameterName = "ResultCode"
    cmdd.Parameters.Add(Paramout)
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()
    cmdKartex.ExecuteNonQuery()

    returnValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ParameterDirection.Output)

    Return returnValue
```

Comment: Please look at the preview the site provides before submitting a question and, if the formatting is a dog's breakfast, fix that first.

Comment: To get a single value from a database, it is likely to be simpler to use ExecuteScalar instead of using an output parameter.